# Can a print expression be stored in a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

```
y=print (-2)
```

Can I run the above command in an interactive python session?  I tried it in Cygwin but it gave me an error.

Comment: The command is valid syntax in Py3 (or in Py2 with ``print_function`` enabled), but it is rather pointless. What are you trying to achieve, a Haskell-like behavior?

Comment: I'm only trying to figure out what the execution is iike as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) function returns `None`, so `y` will be `None`. However, `-2` will be printed.

Just do:

```
y = -2
```

Comment: Exactly.. but why can't I see the -2 printed? Only if I input y , will it give me None.

Comment: @Asher Does this not appear for you? `>>> y = print(-2);
-2;
>>> print(y);
None`

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
    y=print (-2)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax That is what I get instead.

Answer (score 0):

print is a function, and can't be stored in a variable. try something like this:

```
y = -2
print(y)
```

Print(y) prints whatever is in y (in this case, -2)

Answer (score 0):

Just for giggles, you can do this:

```
y = print
```

Which will allow:

```
y(-2)

> -2
```